# Error 500 when moving from localhost to production server

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, phalcon

I try to move my **Phalcon** project from localhost(everything working there) to production server and I see **500 Internal Server Error**. 
There is probably problem with .htaccess file

htaccess in base dir

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule  ^$ public/    [L]
RewriteRule  (.*) public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

htaccess in /public

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?_url=/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Edit: In **error_log** there are `PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Category' not found`

```
$menu = new Category();
$this->view->menu = Category::find(array(
    "order" => "cat_order ASC"
    ));
```

But in models directory I have category class. So every query is fatal error, because controller can not found models class.

Comment: Check the error_log - it could be any number of issues, including database access, PHP version issues, path issues, filesystem permissions issues.   I would rename the .htaccess files so they aren't in use until you can isolate what is wrong with the application files.

Comment: In error_log there are PHP Fatal error

Answer (score 1):

**Solved. The problem was in case sensitivity.**

On localhost I have latest version of Phalcon but on production server there was old version which is case sensitive

Answer (score 0):

When a class has not be found, then it could be that you need to run the `composer install`, or `composer dump-autoload` from the terminal. It could very well be that it will solve the problem.